# In spring tiles configuration file there is a configuration like /{1}.jsp

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a spring tiles configuration file, that contains following lines of code. Can anyone help me in understanding these lines. Also please guide me how to get this path ("/WEB-INF/jsp/contents/{1}.jsp")

```
<definition name="template-main" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/main.jsp">

    <put-attribute name="header-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sections/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="banner-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sections/banner.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sections/footer.jsp" />
</definition>


<!-- anything that doesn't start with a slash is considered a definition here. -->
<definition name="*" extends="template-main">
    <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contents/{1}.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just wildcard support

https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/wildcard.html

Instead of defining multiple definitions for each page

```
<definition name="AAA" extends="template-main">
    <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contents/AAA.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="BBB" extends="template-main">
    <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contents/BBB.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="CCC" extends="template-main">
    <put-attribute name="primary-content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contents/CCC.jsp" />
</definition>
```

the wildcard based definition is defined.

So if you ask for "AAA" tile it is replaced and AAA.jsp is returned